# Testing angular services with another service as a dependancy

Tags: angular, testing, service, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having some issues testing my service (data) with a dependency of another service (API), I need to mock the other service completely but for some reason when i mock the service and then run the tests, API service still runs, and messes with my test cases. How can I completely stop the API service from running?

API Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor() { }

  realCall(){
    console.log('realResult');
  }

}
```

Data Service

```
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService) { }

  callApi() {
    this.apiService.realCall()
  }

}
```

Data Service Test File

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

describe('DataService', () => {
  class mockApiService {
    realCall(){
      console.log('fakeResult');
    }
  }

  let service: DataService;
  let apiService: ApiService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: ApiService, useClass: mockApiService}]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(DataService);
    apiService = TestBed.inject(ApiService)
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('callApi', () => {
    service.callApi()
  })

});
```

When I run the test

```
ng test --include='**/**/data.service.spec.ts' --code-coverage --watch=false
```

It seems like it still runs over in API service too, which I would like it to stop completely.

```
LOG: 'fakeTest'
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.109 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 0 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
WARN: 'Spec 'DataService callApi' has no expectations.'
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.109 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 0 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.109 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.014 secs / 0.009 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 85.71% ( 6/7 )
Branches     : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : 50% ( 2/4 )
Lines        : 80% ( 4/5 )
================================================================================
```

Comment: As you can see in your output, is says "fakeTest" so the method of your mock object is used. Everything fine here...

Comment: It is outputting correctly, but the coverage report still goes through the API service, I expected the mock service to stop that from occuring

Comment: The coverage report will still say that the ApiService is covered if it is being tested independently. Is it being tested independently?

Comment: It is not, that's why im including the --include flag for the specific file.